# Cordova Inappbrowser and Phonegap plugins together?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

is it possible to use device functions like camera in an inappbrowser from cordova? And how it will works?

Comment: It is not possible as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.

What we have done is use event listeners that trigger when the in app browser finishes loading in the  browser.

In the event handler we then look to see what the page is. If it is an add page, we exit the IAB and load onto a custom page. On this page, we access the plug ins. Once we are finished with the plugins, we reopen the IAB and inject the data we collected from the plugins.

This does have a lot of overhead and the result is not as smooth as originally hoped.

If you are just trying to access the camera, you should look at using `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />`